# Calculate latest date for every ID with DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a dataset in Power BI like this:

```
ID      FirstDate    LastDate
214443  07/06/2016  07/06/2017
214443  09/11/2016  09/11/2017
214443  28/09/2018  11/06/2019
214443  31/05/2019  11/06/2019
```

I would like to create two calculated columns that contain the latest date for every index. Currently, I am only able to get the latest date of all the dataset or the same date for every row.

The output should be this:

```
ID      FirstDate   LastDate    FirstDate2  LastDate2
214443  07/06/2016  07/06/2017      
214443  09/11/2016  09/11/2017  07/06/2016  07/06/2017
214443  28/09/2018  11/06/2019  09/11/2016  09/11/2017
214443  31/05/2019  11/06/2019  28/09/2018  11/06/2019
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started with a data like this,

[image]

And then added the Index Column using the query editor,

[image]

And then created a column to check the number of times a single ID is present :-

```
Number of ID's Present = COUNTROWS(FILTER('MyTable', 
     (EARLIER('MyTable'[ID]) = 'MyTable'[ID])))
```

And then wanted to know the starting Index of each ID's to make it easy :-

```
Starting Index = CALCULATE(MIN(MyTable[Index]),FILTER('MyTable', 
     (EARLIER('MyTable'[ID]) = 'MyTable'[ID])))
```

And then now you can do what you are looking for with some easy ways,

```
First Date 2 = 
    Var NumberofIDsPresent = MyTable[Number of ID's Present]
    Var StartingIndex = MyTable[Starting Index]
    Var CurrentIndex = MyTable[Index]

    Var Only_OneTime_ID_Present = IF(OR(NumberofIDsPresent = 1,CurrentIndex = StartingIndex),1,0)
    Var Multiple_Times_ID_Present = CALCULATE(MIN(MyTable[First Date]),FILTER(MyTable, MyTable[Index] = CurrentIndex - 1))
    var result = IF(Only_OneTime_ID_Present = 1, BLANK(),Multiple_Times_ID_Present)
    return result


Last Date 2 = 
    Var NumberofIDsPresent = MyTable[Number of ID's Present]
    Var StartingIndex = MyTable[Starting Index]
    Var CurrentIndex = MyTable[Index]

    Var Only_OneTime_ID_Present = IF(OR(NumberofIDsPresent = 1,CurrentIndex = StartingIndex),1,0)
    Var Multiple_Times_ID_Present = CALCULATE(MIN(MyTable[Last Date]),FILTER(MyTable, MyTable[Index] = CurrentIndex - 1))
    var result = IF(Only_OneTime_ID_Present = 1, BLANK(),Multiple_Times_ID_Present)
    return result
```

Now, this makes my data look something like this,

[image]

Please accept the answer if it helps and Kindly let me know, if it doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: Amazing. Tks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Take the max over the `FirstDate` column only considering rows with matching `ID` and dates before the current row's date.

```
Previous Date =
CALCULATE (
    MAX ( Table1[FirstDate] ),
    FILTER (
        ALLEXCEPT ( Table1, Table1[ID] ),
        Table1[FirstDate] < EARLIER ( Table1[FirstDate] )
    )
)
```

Comment: Alexis, the first date must be different for each ID. Can you help ?

Comment: Did you try it? The `ALLEXCEPT` should enforce the `ID` from the row context to filter the table so it only takes a max over the rows that correspond to that `ID` value.

Comment: @AlexisOlson - I think he wants a different thing... It's a "The previous record" type of problem. Just poor question wording.

Comment: Yes of course. but ALLEXCEPT kept the same date for each ID.

Comment: Ah, yes. Sorry. I took the title as the question rather than your example. Try my edit.